# Spring adding csfrtoken to all forms

Tags: spring, security, http, csrf

Using Spring, we use `CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor` to add an hidden fields to all forms from the getExtraHiddenFields method. However we would like to add it only in POST forms, indeed if a GET form is validated then it might appear in the URL whereas it is not necessary.

How to filter the forms methods ?

Comment: It should already be added only to POST forms. There is a check for other types (at least in 3.2.3).

Comment: The problem may occur because we implements RequestDataValueProcessor and the method getExtraHiddenFields with `lHiddenFields.put(CSRFTokenManager.CSRF_PARAM_NAME, CSRFTokenManager.getTokenFromSession(pRequest));` ? As I understand it there should be a way to add the hidden field automatically without this code shouldn't it ?